# Angular 4 update view after deleting from http server

Tags: javascript, angular, rest, http, service

This is probably asked, but I am looking for a most efficient way to update view in a component which fetches data from server, taking that I delete an item from the server in other component

service

```
   getAllMessages(): Observable<any> {
     return this.http.get('/api/messages/);
       }

   applyTagToMessage(messageId): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.delete('/api/messages/' + messageId)
        }
```

componentA

```
   this.messageService.getAllMessages().subscribe(data = > {
      this.messages = data;
       })


   <div *ngFor="let message of messages">{{message.tags}}</div>
```

componentB

```
 addTagToMessage(messsageId)

   this.messageService.applyTagToMessage(messageId).subscribe(data = > {
      alert("success added tag to message")
       })
   }


   <button (click)="addTagToMessage(messageId)"></button>
```

So the question how to update the componentA which fetches the data from server when I delete the item from server? Should I use async pipe?

Comment: You can Create a Service which holds a list of your data. And if you get a 200 OK from your delete request, just slice this item of your internal list

Answer (score 0):

You can use an EventEmitter in your service whenever you change/reload your data. Then subscribe to that event in component A.

Handle the deletion/adding of the items in component B through your service.

https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter

Answer (score 0):

In my template I do use an async pipe wherever I'm expecting data to change.

`<div *ngFor="let exp of model$ | async">`

Where `model$` is defined as an observable:

`private model$: Observable<Experiment[]>;`